# Group records based on two columns with possible chains

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL and I am anything but good with SQL. I have a long table of records and want to assign them into groups where each member of the group has one of the two columns in common with at least one other member of the group. Ideally by creating a table containing of all distinct values from either column (there are no overlaps there as they are totally different character values) and the number of the group they belong to.

I expect some groups to be consisting of only the one member but there may be long chains of relations where two records are not connected but a third record connects them. Using a programming language (e.g. JavaScript) I would possibly use a recursive function but with SQL I am lost.

I have tried searching for an answer but I find it hard to come up with suitable key words. It is kind of like an enormous domino game but still a bit different. Is there any simple solution for this problem? And if not, can someone please point me in a good direction?

**Edit:**
Some example data. userId and session are my two columns. So in this case Id 2, 4, and 6 would be in the same group.

```
Id   Type      userID                session
1    callback  25596094              lJcD7fiFCnB4o4ZxI_DQHKMmBGW1T0b4
2    callback  26631605              xupFcU6C8cl7wdviOnc1XX37Feg234vK
3    callback  02-9128924-01         eNE8VuJBz9vffGeuALy72owq1cJhK84l
4    callback  26631605              GhenxfiVXQaGbYq2_SXJhhkvTRN8M3vb
5    callback  globetrotter-394146   PdJEDeW57piXMu6nNsJjLZeFmNrP2jvG
6    callback  31831125              xupFcU6C8cl7wdviOnc1XX37Feg234vK
```

Comment: A recursive query can easily get all related rows from a starting one, and assign the same "group id" to all found rows. Now, you would need to run it multiple times to work with the second, third, fourth groups ad infinitum.

Comment: Please add some sample data, so it's easier for us to understand the specifics. Just a few rows will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a partial solution that will retrieve all rows "related" to a first one, based on your logic.

In this case if we start with row (id = 4), the query could be:

```
with recursive
x as (
  select * from my_table where id = 4 -- this is the starting row
  union all
  select t.* 
  from my_table t
  join x on t.userID = x.userId or t.session = x.session
)
select * from x
```

And the result will be:

```
Id   Type      userID                session
4    callback  26631605              GhenxfiVXQaGbYq2_SXJhhkvTRN8M3vb
2    callback  26631605              xupFcU6C8cl7wdviOnc1XX37Feg234vK
6    callback  31831125              xupFcU6C8cl7wdviOnc1XX37Feg234vK
```

The query needs more work to make it run for all rows, not just a subset like in this case.

**UPDATE Dec 7, 2018:**

I wrote a SQL update that will find **one** group and assign a new (different) `group_id` value to it. If you run this SQL update multiple times you'll eventually assign group ids to all rows. Here it is:

```
alter table my_table add group_id int; -- extra column stores the group_id

create sequence group_id_seq; -- will generate a different group_id each time

with recursive
s as (
  select nextval('group_id_seq') as nv
),
x as (
  select * from (
    select * from my_table where group_id is null fetch first 1 rows only
  ) x
  union
  select t.*
  from my_table t
  join x on t.userid = x.userid or t.session = x.session
)
update my_table t set group_id = s.nv from s, x where t.id = x.id;
```

Again, each time you run it, it will mark a new [unmarked] set of rows with a new group id value.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't this keep selecting the same row over and over again? When I run something similar it takes ages and returns the same row multiple times. I changed 'union all' to 'union' and it looks better.

Comment: Yes, it's only work in progress. In order to select new ones, you'll need to "mark" the ones already taken. Maybe you could add an extra column called `group_id` that is initially null, and is populated with a new group id coming from a sequence. The other thing is, the starting point (id = 4) should probably come from a query that gets any (only one) random row form which `group_id` is null. Let me try in a sec.

Comment: Please try out the `UPDATE` I wrote. It peaked my interest. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works great! I put it inside a function and loop it until there are no nulls in group_id. Thanks a lot! Would have never come up with such a compact solution.