# Having a table of elements equality , calculate number of "unique" elements

Tags: mysql, combinations

I have two tables:
table of product ids:

table p_test:

```
id:

1

2

3

4
```

and a table of all possible combinations of a product tested with every other product for equality (let't say I test their pictures and if the pictures are equal - I assume they are same product):
table p_match_test:

```
p_id_1, p_id_2, is_same

1       2       0

1       3       0

1       4       1

2       3       1

2       4       0

3       4       0
```

as you can see in this example there is total of 4 products. Product 1 was tested for equality with product 4 and they were found "same", same thing about products 2 and 3.
This means that there are only two "unique" products (2 unique pictures for 4 products).

What I want to achieve is to have a count of unique pictures in any group of products so the result will be:

```
products_count unique_products_count
4              2
```

I tried this query:

```
select count(p.id)                                                                                                            as products_count,
       sum(if(not exists(select * from p_match_test t where (p.id = t.p_id_1 or p.id = t.p_id_2) and t.is_same = 1), 1, 0)) as unique_products_count
from p_test p
```

but it counts only products that have **no** duplicates instead of counting "unique" images.
How do I achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you need "transitive" equality? What if product #1 is equivalent to #5 and #5 is equivalent to #8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group records based on two columns with possible chains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656062/group-records-based-on-two-columns-with-possible-chains)

Comment: Yes, but for your case, there always will be an entry for 1,5,1; 1,8,1 and 5,8,1 in p_match_test table. I mean no “implied” equality need to be inferred.

Comment: Apart from sql, this is problem of [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) usually solved with disjoint sets